# Computer reboots after a noise when monitor is switched off

Tags: display

My computer reboots after a noise and grey screen when my monitor(Samsung Syncmaster 591s) is switched off.

It was repaired a day back (it was getting off and had to hit/tap on it to return back to normal.)

Comment: @user56932 could you please clarify your question? It is difficult to determine if your computer is the problem, or if it is the monitor which is the problem. When you say "it" was repaired, do you mean the computer itself or the monitor?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier if you describe the noise.

It is very hard to help you, but, if the noise is a loud clicking/high pitch squeek, it is most likely the hard drive has gone wrong - however, this usually results in a freeze rather than a restart.

If it is a sound that sort of repeats the last second or so of whatever you are currently listening to, it could be anything - most common causes are bad drivers, bad memory or other bad hardware component.

I hope this helps.

Comment: it was a noise inside monitor probably...now its working ok ...have not tried to switch off monitor again...(there is a power button on monitor beside color, contrast buttons)

Comment: If the noise is coming from inside the monitor, the computer should not restart. However, I would check that the power cable is firmly in the monitor and not loose.